# Three.js - How to access created scene from another class

Tags: javascript, three.js, parameter-passing

I want to pass my scene constant to another class and use it there. But when I try to use it, it gives error of

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'scene' of undefined

The one in below is my main file which I do everything:

```
class Main
{
constructor()
{
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xaaaaaa );
    .
    .
    .
     /* some other code */

}

Init()
{
    
    /* other code */

    // Define constructor class and PASS SCENE CONST to it
    const cityConstructor = new Constructor(1, this.scene); //<-- THIS IS WHERE I PASS
    cityConstructor.ConstructCity();
}
}


const main = new Main();
main.Init();
```

And this is the class I passed the variable:

```
export class Constructor{
constructor(cellWidth, scene){
    
    this.scene = scene;//document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].scene; // I tried other things as well
    this.loader = new GLTFLoader();

}

LoadAsset(block, xPos, yPos)
{
    // load a resource
    this.loader.load( 
        '../assets/'+ block.name,

        function ( gltf ) {
            const model = gltf.scene;
            model.position.set(xPos, 0, yPos);
            this.scene.add( model ); // <--- THIS IS WHERE ERROR IS

        },
         /*Other code*/

    );
}
 .
 .
 .
 /* Other code */
```

**Now I want to ask what is best practice for accessing THREE.scene object from other classes?**

Comment: this.scene = main.scene;

Comment: these classes not in same file so I don't have access to main object. Are you saying I should pass main object to other class and then access the scene?

Comment: If anyone curious, don't pass scene object the constructor of another class just pass it to function. For some reason if you pass it to constructor it will become undefined.

Comment: I think you're already doing it the right way. When calling `new Constructor(1, this.scene);`, you're already passing the scene object to your child class so it can be used inside that child. Have you tried calling your class something else than `Constructor`? Your Engine might be running into problems because the keyword `constructor` is reserved, and it might be confusing the two. Also, what's inside the `ConstructCity()` method?